# Deleted question/answer is visible

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-answers

I wonder why are deleted answers still visible to people with enough reputation. I'm not comfortable with this. Is it possible to change that. If I delete something then I don't want anyone to see my deleted post. What is the purpose of deleteing if people can still see?

**Edit after an answer and comment:** Deleting is therefore a misleading word. Would not it be better if we used the word shading or something similar instead of deleting?

Comment: If you spend 22.9k points in bounties, you won't have to deal with this problem any longer.

Comment: Also, the purpose is to help the community moderate itself. It means that people can undo deletions that they think were inappropriate, it adds a level of transparency to moderation, which is good. And it helps to identify patterns of problematic users.

Comment: Deleting is still an appropriate term:  deleted meaning no longer subject to downvotes (or upvotes) or questions/answers; and for most answers, not visible to askers, not visible, or not "acceptable".

Comment: Remember, that upon submission of a question or an answer, it is no longer the author's "property": it belongs to SE.  So it makes sense that there is only one level of "deletion" possible, (or other levels I'm not privy to access).  All the more reason to take care when choosing to post a question or an answer.

Comment: There's not many users with enough reputation to see the deleted posts. And I, for one, am very grateful for being able to see deleted answers for reference, especially for old, difficult question. I also see a lot of deleted answers edited to hide the content, and it's fine too. I don't think more than 2 or 3 people on the site would go into the edits history just to see what the attempt was about. That said, this question is valid, and I upvoted it

Comment: Also, read [that damn fine print of legalese](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/licensing). By posting you granted SE certain rights to the content.

Answer (score 8):

The main reason why deleted posts are still visible is to allow to review deletions.

If there is a very urgent need to get something deleted more definitely there are ways to do this. Flag and explain the reason, but be prepared for it to be declined except if there is a *very* good reason.

Comment: Not really a formal way, you can just raise a flag. But generally everybody please do not go overboard with this. I wrote "very urgent need" not "good reason." Deleted threads are rather hard to find at least after some time (deleted answers on visible questions are a different matter).

Comment: Agree with quid. Just posting a reminder to any future reader (obvious and/or irrelevant to the present viewers of this thread). *The fact that your teacher may see that you are outsourcing homework is neither a "good reason" nor a "very urgent need".* It's just that I've seen enough of that in my time :-/